# How to have different return types based input object?

Tags: typescript

I have a method to filter a list based on some fileds and sometimes I can have an extra pageNumber and limit for which to filter my list and get only a limited number of entries.

This is what I have in code:

```
public getByFilter(
   fitler?: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] } & { pageNumber?: number; limit?: number }
 ): Observable<IPagedResult<T>> { // code to filter }
```

and using this method

```
.getByFilter({ ...filters })
      .subscribe((response: IPagedResult<MyClass>) => {
        // do something
      });
```

Can my method have a return type of

```
Observable<T[]>
```

if my filters object does not contain pageNumber and limit?

and then to use it like

```
.getByFilter({ ...filters })
      .subscribe((response: MyClass[]) => {
        // do something
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently only possible with some hacky casting on the implementation side, the issue is being tracked however ([#24929](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929), [#22735](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735), [#22596](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22596)) and the maintainers declared it as a [design limition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735#issuecomment-376960435).

The solution is to define the `filter` parameter as generic parameter like this:

```
type BasicFilter<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] };
type PaginationFilter<T> = BasicFilter<T> & { pageNumber: number, limit: number };
type Filter<T> = BasicFilter<T> | PaginationFilter<T>;

public getByFilter<F extends Filter<T>>(filter: F): F extends PaginationFilter<T> ? Observable<IPagedResult<T>> : Observable<T> {
    /**/
}
```

the return type is being infered based on whether input is a pagination filter or basic filter.

This works as expected on the call side:

```
const paged = new Observable<Test>({foo: 1, bar: ''}).getByFilter({
   pageNumber: 2,
   limit: 2,
});
// paged as type: Observable<IPagedResult<Test>>

const raw = new Observable<Test>({foo: 1, bar: ''}).getByFilter({});
// raw as type: Observable<Test>
```

On the implementation side you need a asseration `as any` like this (the mentioned issue which is being tracked on GitHub):

```
if ('pageNumber' in filter && 'limit' in filter) {
  return new Observable<IPagedResult<T>>({
     data: this.value,
  }) as any;
}
return this as any;
```

A full example can be found [here in this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=7&pln=20&pc=26#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwJYGMBiSA2wICcA8AKgHxQC8UA3lANoAKUSAdlANYQgD2AZlIQLoB%20AFx96-KAF8A3AChQkKHTgBzZnGBJOTDNjxFSFeMnRYcBElABkVKGFUQAcgFcAtgCM8opm8%204ANFCYSK5IwN6%20eFJyCtC65gbksIio8fqWAD5Kquqa2mkWxHKy8uDQAJLKKhAAJgBKEAjO2IkU1DUacKKE0SUomIgIUADy7gh4AG5w7pgQiZSyUEtguEhTOFBTmM4Q3XJLUCjaCMC4zijAnLgAFFs73QCUVIsHS8AAFkgIAHR30BR-fZLSQlA5gZwzVBQarAGAgAr4NBQCAADxwTBqQwRJGI124Zi8UDQD1ESNR6Mx2TUTA0Wh0BMKUEEIzGk2ms3wlQc9UazWABlIolG41wUxmc0sC1eSyQvGuAHJ7NUXB48PLGCx8XpcNYbPLgqFgOrmFAteYnlLpQdcBBgM5cCwmBAAO4skVijlc6o8potHHXS1W14dYBdKAfL6-ODbCD%20F5ByRPRBQOBMEBA14gq02u0O8OfIbJ1Pp%20MgkGlRSERrAJKB7icTgRVUBePuOC4UQnVZMFRxmR9Y41pW1JJO13CtniojV3GUeuNqAARkCbY7UHl8sT3xhcIKAfjw5VflEACY4wcDWFT32HgOmCcoLg4K6KGO3ZOOVWTrP56Jl1BV1EDctx3eEGQDRNpCAA).